# Jenkins "Build Now" menu missing after upgrading from 1.638 to 2.1

Tags: jenkins, upgrade

Using the script found here: https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Automated+Upgrade, I've upgrade my Jenkins on my local Windows 7 PC from 1.638 to 2.1. First thing I notice is these two menu only left with icon but no words. Any idea?

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Restart the machine seems fixed this issue.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you log in. Some functionality is hidden if you haven't logged in.